# How to install older VLC 2.2 after having 3.0?

Tags: apt

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1-3) but 3.0.0~~git20151218+r62827+34~ubuntu15.10.1 is to be installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
```

What do I do?

Comment: Tried installing each one separately?

Comment: How did you install VLC 3.0?

Comment: I have finally solved it by removing vlc-nox and doing sudo apt-get autoremove. But ppa was allready gone before I done that. Will check out that other thread though

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc-nox
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```